# Decide different outcomes of team position by score

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know if this is the right place to ask such a question but I hope so! I'm developing a game for fun where you have different teams who get points for each kick they can do in volley with a football. When the game is over I'm counting the score of each team and sort them by the best score.

So say:

```
team 1 = 9 points
team 2 = 7 points
team 3 = 20 points
```

Then I've sorted it by the best one, so the positions are:

```
team 3 = 20 points
team 1 = 9 points
team 2 = 7 points
```

Then I print it on the screen and say like "Team 3 comes on first place with 20 points". "Team 1...second", "team 2 .....third".

The problem is when some of the teams get the same score. So say it ends up like this:

```
team 1 = 9 points
team 2 = 9 points
team 3 = 20 points
```

In such case I want it to print like: "Team 3 comes on first place with 20 points", "Team 1 and Team 2 comes on second place with 9 points each".

Here is the problem, I've been thinking and thinking but I can't come up with a smart solution of how to make the code consider a shared first/second/third place.

Here is my current code that doesn't take account of that:

```
 for var i = 0; i < teamScoreArray.count; ++i  { //sorted array by best score first
            var tmpTeam:Team = teamScoreArray[i]

            if i == 0{
                firstPlacelbl.text = "On first place comes \(tmpTeam.teamName) with \(tmpTeam.teamScore) points"
            }
            if i == 1{
                secondPlacelbl.text = "On second place comes \(tmpTeam.teamName) with \(tmpTeam.teamScore) points"
            }
            if i == 2{
                thirdPlacelbl.text = "On third place comes \(tmpTeam.teamName) with \(tmpTeam.teamScore) points"
            }
            if i == 3{
                fourthPlacelbl.text = "On fourth place comes \(tmpTeam.teamName) with \(tmpTeam.teamScore) points"
            }
            prevScore = tmpTeam.teamScore
        }
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to make this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the rank only when the score in the current iteration differs from the previous one:

```
var rank = 0
var previousScore = 0

for team in teamScoreArray {
    if team.teamScore != previousScore {
        rank += 1
    }

    println("Rank \(rank): \(team.teamName)")

    previousScore = team.teamScore
}
```

Comment: I will try this out later on today and mark your answer as the right one! Thanks